# Regex to extract data between two pipe symbols

Tags: regex

I am looking to extract "2" from the query parameter using Regex -

```
http://www.example.com?param=1|2|3|4|test&param1=5|6
```

Regex used -

```
.*param=.*\|(\w+)\|.*
```

The output I get is "4".

I have even tried this to no avail -

```
.*param=.*\|(.*?)\|.*
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the first `.*` non-greedy:

```
param=.*?\|(\w+)\|
```

or make it not match a pipe:

```
param=[^|]*\|(\w+)\|
```

Answer (score 1):

Using you regex, simply add a `?` after `.*` to capture **as less characters as possible** :

```
.*param=.*?\|(\w+)\|.*
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\|(\w+)\|
```

Try this .See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rQ5jJ3/1